# Chaining signal handlers in ncurses

Tags: c++, signals, ncurses

My Ncurses app is looping for keyboard input and prints output to the screen. When I'm stopping my app (ctrl+z) and later resuming it, I have noticed that input buffer sometimes contains unwanted characters. So I want to enrich SIGCONT handler by default provided by ncurses with flushinp(), simplified code below:

```
#include <csignal>
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>

struct sigaction oldact, newact;
extern "C" void sigContHandler(int sig)
{
    std::ofstream of("sc", std::ofstream::app);
    of << "Handling cont " << std::endl;
    flushinp();
    //Call old handler, but crash as it is always 0
    (oldact.sa_handler)(sig);
}

    int main(void)
    {
        initscr();
        cbreak();
        noecho();
        clear();

        newact.sa_handler = sigContHandler;
        newact.sa_flags = 0;
        sigemptyset (&newact.sa_mask);
        sigaction(SIGCONT, &newact, &oldact);

        int c = 0;
        while (c = getch()) {
            if (c == 'q')
                break;
            mvaddch(0, 0, c);
        }
    refresh();
    endwin();
    exit(0);
}
```

I can't call old SIGCONT handler as it is always 0. Obviously this default handler is successfully called if I don't add code to chain signal handlers. I don't understand why I can't call old handler, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What prevents you from checking if `sa_handler` is NULL before you call it? This is what the system would do before attempting to call a handler.

Answer (score 0):

I find nothing in `flushinp`'s documentation that indicates that it is signal-safe. Because of what signals are, and how they work, by default any library functions -- especially third party libraries -- are presumed by default to be ***not signal safe*** unless documented otherwise. As such they ***cannot*** be called from an asynchronous signal handler.

Note, for example, that the [signal-safety(7) manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/signal-safety.7.html) explicitly enumerates ***the only C library functions*** that are signal-safe. Unless the function is on the list, it cannot be called from a signal handler. None of the C++ library classes, templates, and functions, are signal-safe.

If all your signal handler did was called the original handler (if it was not NULL, and do nothing if it was NULL), it would be fine. But the invocation of `flushinp` introduces undefined behavior, and that's the end of the line.

The only way to do this safely, on Linux, is to use [a signal file descriptor](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html), effectively turning an asynchronous signal handler into a file descriptor event, and implement multiplexed non-blocking `poll` loop for standard input and the signal file descriptor, integrated with the curses library. This is quite complicated, and will require quite a bit of work. It is also unclear what is the source of your unwanted input. Input doesn't materialize out of thin air, so there must be a reason for that, and you might want to look in that direction, first, instead of attempting to address the effect, rather than the cause.

Comment: When my handler function don't have anything else other than '(oldact.sa_handler)(sig);' the problem persist

Comment: I pointed this out by the "if not NULL" part. There is no "old handler" at all.